# In WCF Service Json Data Output DateTime How to be Formatted?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, wcf

Using Mongodb in wcf i am getting json data in that my output is like this

```
{
    "JobSearchResult":"[{\"JobId\":\"JO1101\",
    **\"ExpiryDate\":\"\\\/Date(1737538921565)\\\/\",**
    \"Location\":\"Mumbai\",
    \"Experience\":\"1-6Year\"}]",
    "Count":1,"status":1
 }
```

see the ExpiryDate it is in mongodb format I have to get output as `Date(25/02/2015`) like this ..and how to remove the backslashes in json ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you using linq to get value from mongodb in wcf. so u asking in (25/02/2015) this type format as date in output.

kindly do two things

1) change the datatype as string in class

```
public string Date { get; set;}
```

2) get the output object date as this format

`Date = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", obj.Date).ToString(),`

You will sure get 25/02/2015.

Comment: Thanks... Working Perfectly.I searched in google there is no answer u really brilliant, talent, genius,extraordinary man.keep it up.

Comment: Thanks buddy its simple ya